# Prepare for segue passing Data nil

Tags: swift, firebase, uistoryboardsegue

I literally changed none of the code, but after updating to Xcode 12, the prepare for Segue method to pass Data doesn't work anymore.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetails" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath, let nextVC = segue.destination as? JobDetailViewController {
            nextVC.jobDetails =
                JobDetailViewController.JobDetails(jobDetail: jobs[indexPath.row].text, userName: jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser!, jobImage: jobs[indexPath.row].jobImage, downloadURL: jobs[indexPath.row].downloadURL!)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: indexPath.row)
```

}

DetailedVC:

```
var jobDetails: JobDetails?

struct JobDetails {
    var jobDetail: String
    var userName: String
    var jobImage: UIImage?
    var downloadURL: String?
}
```

(for example)
By **print("Hello (jobDetails?.userName)")** I'm getting **"Hello nil"** as output

Did anything has been changed with the new Swift/Xcode version?
I'm also not getting any errors/warnings

Comment: Are the lines of code called? `ùnextVC.jobDetails`? If yes could you check if it's before or after ` print("Hello (jobDetails?.userName)") `?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the print statement afterwards :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look, you are passing indexPath.row which is Int and in prepare you are parsing it to IndexPath.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: indexPath)
    }
```

Comment: Wow, this was it... dude thank you so so much, you literally saved me a ton of time, god bless you my friend